# How to send data as JSON with form submit?

Tags: forms

I am building an Application using Angular/Node.
In my application, I need to submit a form with JSON data. 
I am appending some input fields in that form with some name_attribute and value=JSON data.

In my server code(written in Node) when I receive the value using : request.body.name_attribute, the JSON is becoming a String and I have to do a JSON.parse(value) to be able to use it.

But, I do not want to use JSON.parse(...) in the server side as it may leave my application prone to script attacks.

Is there a way to send JSON data using a form.submit() without the data getting automatically converted to string?

[*Answers specific to sending JSON data(without the data getting changed to string) with form submit would really be appreciated ;)]

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON.Parse on the server side should be perfectly safe, as JSON.Parse will simply throw an error if the input is not valid JSON. JSON can only hold data, no code.

Indeed, if you are worried about security, there is really very little you can do client side to protect your system, as a malicious attacker may transmit anything he or she wishes to your server.